# Well known free Javascript (assistance) chat for integrating in a webapp

Tags: web-apps, javascript, chat, irc

I am developing a webapp for the sales department of my company, and I would like to integrate a chat to allow them asking for direct technical support from us developers. My constraints are the folowing:

- the software must be free
- In case there would be a server part, it must be perl, bash or java because I will have to test it on an old solaris where compiling a C-program or installing a package would be very complicated.
- I would like to prevent users from talking to each other, or at least control who can speak to who.
- I would like admin users being able to send broadcast messages to every user online
- I don't need a super modern tool. Actually we are still supporting IE8 so I'd rather it'd work with IE8 even if this means I have to use a version from several years ago.
- Since the main goal is a two people conversation about the webapp, it would be better if the chat integrates as a small window rather than using the whole screen and if it is still possible to navigate within the application while chatting.
- Finally I'd prefer if it was a well known solution used a lot around the world even if it means it is a general purpose tool I will have to customize.

Do you have an Idea of what could be suited to those needs? I thought about using an IRC server or a Jabber/Xmpp server and then find a compatible javascript chat library, but did not find a really convincing solution.

Comment: IRC is more suited for Chatrooms.